# Is there any way to handle canvas.toBlob with observables in rxjs?

Tags: canvas, rxjs

I've been trying to handle `canvas.toBlob` with observables in rxjs instead of promise or callbacks. `bindCallback` operator seems to fit so I've tried like:

```
bindCallback(canvas.toBlob)().pipe(
  map((blob: Blob) => URL.createObjectURL(blob))
);
```

but it gives me `ERROR TypeError: Illegal invocation` error.

If the operator doesn't fit, any other idea for this?
Appreciate any insight. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the function `canvas.toBlob` loses the invocation context.

You'd have the same issue if you try this:

```
const toBlob = canvas.toBlob;

toBlob(blob => console.log('hello'));
// ERROR TypeError: Illegal invocation
```

this function, `toBlob` is internally using `this`, but as you're not calling it from an object `this` is undefined.

Solution is to bind it to the original canvas:

```
bindCallback(canvas.toBlob.bind(canvas))().pipe(
  map((blob: Blob) => URL.createObjectURL(blob))
);
```

Comment: It gives me `Argument of type 'OperatorFunction<Blob, string>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'OperatorFunction<any[], string>'.
  Type 'Blob' is missing the following properties from type 'any[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 27 more.` compile error.

Comment: You're probably putting `.bind` in the wrong position? Note that it's `canvas.toBlob.bind(canvas)`, not `canvas.toBlob).bind(canvas)`

Comment: My bad, it's not that. It's probably the types of `map((blob: Blob` - Try changing that to any and see what are the types you're receiving on runtime.... It seems like it expects any[]?

Comment: If I change the type to any, the compile error is gone but I don't understand why it's expecting the any[] at the compile error.

Comment: Yep, that's strange. In theory you don't need to specifiy the type inside map, typescript should figure it out by itself. I just tested in my environment, TS@4.2.3 rxjs@6.6.6 and it works correctly, the type inside map is inferred as (blob: Blob | null) => ...

Comment: Yeah strange. My environment is rxjs@6.4.0 and TS@3.5.3 FYI